# Stopping a thread after a certain amount of time while keeping the main thread responsive

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm looking to terminate a thread after a certain amount of time. The thread is called from an infinite while loop that waits for users input. Thread starts after user inputs number 4 from command line, after which thread writes some text to the console in another infinite loop. After x amount of time the started thread should terminate. How can I make the thread stop after the set time while keeping the main thread with user input responsive (active)?

Here is some sample code:

```
def loop():
    while True:
        print("ON")
        print("OFF")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop)

    try:
        while True:
            print(">>", end='')
            command = int(input())

            if command == 1:
                ...
            elif command == 2:
                ...
            elif command == 3:
                ...
            elif command == 4:
                print("Insert time:")
                time = float(input())
                t.start()
            elif command == 5:
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to pass an argument to the loop and that can be used to stop the thread, something like this:

```
def loop(running):
    while running[0]:
        print("HELLO")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    running = [True]
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop, args=(running,))
    t.start()

    while True:
        command = input()
        running[0] = False
```

running is shared by both the main thread and the other thread, so changing the value in one changes it in the other.

Comment: As i understand from the question, he want to stop the subthread in specific timeout, but `input()` function can block forever and subthread can't terminate in specific timeout.

Comment: It's just a minimal working example - the `input()` bit can be replaced with whatever logic one wants.